# Apache Karaf 4 debug in Docker container

Tags: java, docker, xdebug, apache-karaf

I have a karaf based application that runs inside a docker container.
In karaf 3, when I started the app with the `debug` flag the debugging server was listening on:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/java
```

After I moved to karaf 4 it is listening on:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      55/java
```

Becuase of that the server won't listen for connection arriving from my IDE.

Anyone knows how to configure `karaf` to start the server on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can configure this in the `$KARAF_HOME/etc/org.apache.karaf.management.cfg` file.

regards,

Comment: In the management.cfg there are only the following host IP addresses:
rmiRegistryHost, rmiServerHost, jmxmpHost. Which one is the host I should change to configure the debug host?

Answer (score 0):

To debug Karaf >= 4 in docker, you have to prefix the port with `*:`, e.g. `*:5005` or whatever you want the debug port to be. This can be defined by exporting the env variable JAVA_DEBUG_PORT before starting karaf. You can do this e.g. in the *entrypoint.sh* of your karaf docker workspace before you execute `karaf run`:

```
export KARAF_DEBUG=true
export JAVA_DEBUG_PORT="*:5005"
/opt/karaf/bin/karaf run
```

Or by using any of the usual means to [set environment variables in docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/).

You can also set JAVA_DEBUG_OPTS to have full control over the debug configuration, e.g. you might want to set `suspend=y` (wait for the debugger to attach):

```
JAVA_DEBUG_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"
```

As an alternative, if your container image passes arguments to the karaf script, you can pass the following arguments to the script in order to debug or debug suspending:

```
karaf debug
karaf debugs
```